# Тестовая задачка

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Можете помочь решить задачку которую дали на стажировке, только не так что бы прямо код, а обьяснили в первую очередь какие темы изучить что подтянуть и тд. вообщем надо сделать на asp.net(framework 5 старый стек) такую задачку:
Допустим есть пару блоков на нашей странице, наша задача это сделать так что бы они содержали в себе контент а контент внутри должен содержать еще контент, все это должно быть адаптивно что бы была бесконечная прокрутка в случае добавления огромного количества содержания, как усложнение добавить кнопку настройки к каждому элементу родителя и самому родителю
где можно редактировать, удалять элемент и тд
что делать, можете дать максимальное количество подсказок

Comment: начните с того, чтобы формлуровку задачи разбить на пункты, и определиться, с чем именно у вас возникают проблемы.

Comment: говоря открыто, прямо со всем в целом, сам асп-нет мвс 5 начал изучать буквально дня три назад, знаю основы основ и все. мне нужно что бы мне подсказали на какие вещи ориентироваться в целом для решения

Comment: Вопрос по вёрстке. Сделать её можно разными способами. Ищите по терминам adaptive layout или responsive layout.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну кстати да, я так же думал, но я задаю себе вопрос, а можно ли тут прикрутить гайки по асп